# convert query from mysql to php laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

My query is the following:

`select employe.id, employe.nam, users.name, users.name_user 
from employe 
left join users
on users.name = employe.id`

it is a query to two tables: employe, users.

How can I pass it to my controller? Am I new to laravel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Laravel** use a MVC pattern, a good practice is use a **Model** for your **employe** table

I recomend you to use an **Eloquen Model**, so, your query will look like this:

```
Employe::select('employe.id', 'employe.nam', 'users.name', 'users.name_user')
       ->leftJoin('users', 'users.name', 'employes.id')
       ->get();
```

Comment: Your table is named 'employe', then your model needs a table name override, you need to pass the `protected $table = 'employe';`.

Comment: And what will be returned? Employe model with a mix of related and unrelated attributes. I'd rather have std class returned in this case than a twisted Eloquent model.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the user to employee is a [One to One](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relation.
Did you setup the relation in both models?

If so you can do the following in your controller:

```
$employees = Employee::with('user')->all();
```

This will load all employees and the related user.
Question is the users.name a foreign key on the employee.id? 
Thats a bit strange, i recommend using id's on both models (autoIncrement).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily maintain this kind of query with **Eloquent relationships**.

Add this method on your employee model

```
public function user(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\User','name','id');
}
```

Add this method on your user model

```
public function Employee(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee','id','name');
}
```

Add line on your controller

```
$employees = Employee::with('user')->all();
```